# ajax in django success function is not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, function

I am new in ajax as well as Django. I try to put ajax in my code to check that in the signup page if some user is already having one email then that email can't use for new users and disable the button else if the email does not exist then the user can be created.

**ajaxCode**

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="email"]', function(){
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/stock/checkemail/',
    data:{
        email:$("#email").val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(){
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'true')
    },
    failure:function(){
        $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
   })
});
```

**url.py**

```
    path('checkemail/',Emailser.as_view()),
```

**views.py**

```
class Emailser(View):
    def post(self, request):
        em = request.POST['email']
        print(em)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=em)
            return HttpResponse('true')
        except:
            return HttpResponse('false')
```

In views.py `print(em)` is also printing mail that type in field but don't know why is not working.
**template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<div>
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
  {% if error %}
{{error}}
<br/>
{% endif %}
  <form method="post" id="signup" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
     <script src="{% static 'assets/signup.js' %}" ></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So what error do you got? Can you give more details?

Comment: @FurkanÖyken there is no error on console and a server. but my functionality not working. When I type the mail address in the email field which already exists in the database move toward the next password field it needs to show me an error 'email already exists' and disable the submit button but it's not doing that work.

Answer (score 0):

try this inside succcess function

```
$('input[type="submit"]').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="email"]', function(){
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/stock/checkemail/',
    data:{
        email:$("#email").val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(response){
        response ? $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'true') :  $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');

    },
    failure:function(error){
     console.log(error);
    }
   })
});
```

Comment: go to the console and see the error after this ajax request is fired. and also try console.log(response) in success to see what might get logged

Comment: it's giving me `true`

Comment: yep..but that's mean email exist and it should disable the button. That's not working